# Why can't I compile OpenSSL with multiple threads? (make -j3)

Tags: c, linux, openssl, makefile

I'm trying to build OpenSSL. If I build it with `make` (1 thread), it compiles okay. But if I build it with 3 threads (`make -j3`), I get LOTS of linker errors:

```
bntest.o: In function `message':
bntest.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `BIO_puts'
bntest.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `BIO_puts'
bntest.o: In function `test_add':
bntest.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `BN_init'
bntest.c:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `BN_init'
bntest.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `BN_init'
bntest.c:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `BN_bntest_rand'
bntest.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `BN_print'
bntest.c:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `BIO_puts'
bntest.c:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `BN_add'
bntest.c:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `BN_add'
bntest.c:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `BN_bntest_rand'
bntest.c:(.text+0x1d3): undefined reference to `BN_add'
bntest.c:(.text+0x1f5): undefined reference to `BN_print'
bntest.c:(.text+0x202): undefined reference to `BIO_puts'
bntest.c:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `BN_print'
bntest.c:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to `BIO_puts'
bntest.c:(.text+0x264): undefined reference to `BN_free'
bntest.c:(.text+0x26e): undefined reference to `BN_free'
bntest.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `BN_free'
bntest.o: In function `test_sub':
bntest.c:(.text+0x2af): undefined reference to `BN_init'
bntest.c:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `BN_init'
bntest.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `BN_init'
bntest.c:(.text+0x2e0): undefined reference to `BN_bntest_rand'
bntest.c:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `BN_sub'
...and so on, for hundreds of lines...
```

To be clear, the exact sequence of commands I ran is:

```
$ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.0.1l
$ ./config
$ make -j3
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10 on an x64 machine.

This might be an RTFM-type question, but I haven't been able to see anywhere that says building OpenSSL with multiple threads is not supported.

So the question: **Is building OpenSSL with multiple threads supported? If so, what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: To be pedantic, make is not multithreaded and doesn't use threading to achieve parallelism.  In any event, it seems pretty clear from the results you're getting that openssl does _not_ support parallel jobs in make (`-j`), regardless of whether this is explicitly stated or not.  Too bad openssl decided to roll their own configure/make environment instead of using autotools, which supports parallel jobs in make by default.

Comment: @MadScientist: If `make` is not multithreaded, does that mean it will `fork()` and `exec()` the job process (i.e. `gcc`), and spawn N processes (where N is the number of `--jobs`)? And then just `wait()` for a child process to exit before spawning another job (to make sure to keep the number of running jobs <= N)? Is that how its parallelism is implemented?

Comment: Correct.  The slow part of building is not (typically) the processing make does, but rather the processing the compiler or whatever build tools make invokes do.  So in parallel make, it simply runs more tools at the same time.  Not being multithreaded saves a lot of complexity in make itself, especially since the original code was written 30+ years ago before multithreaded programs were common: it uses a lot of global variables, etc.

Comment: You could also look at fixing the makefile. I think there are two recipies of interest. I don't have Stallman's [GNU Make](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1882114825) book handy, so I can't tell you how to do it :( But there's an easy way to express build rule dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As MadScientist's comment indicates a makefile has to be designed to support parallel builds. Apparently OpenSSL is supposed to support parallel make but one of their [bug reports](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2364&user=guest&pass=guest) shows that this support has on a few occasions been broken. This bug was most recently marked as fixed on December 12th, 2014, so it's possible that using a newer version of OpenSSL will fix the problem you've encountered.

Comment: I have tried to compile OpenSSL 1.0.2 on i5 (dualcore, HT). It doesn't throw any error. However, it doesn't speed up dramatically.
```make  92,81s user 12,94s system 100% cpu 1:45,66 total
make -j2  102,38s user 12,60s system 142% cpu 1:20,50 total
make -j4  108,85s user 13,26s system 151% cpu 1:20,42 total```

Comment: @zakjan I wouldn't necessarily expect it to speed up dramatically. Makefiles often have bottlenecks where commands can't be run in parallel (eg. the final link step) and it's possible that other factors like memory bandwidth or disk I/O limit how fast it can be built.